# Is it truly necessary to follow each and every rule of islam to go to heaven?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

This is about me. I was born as a muslim but since i am not from a country where a lot of people follow islam and my family is a but chill. I don’t know and have not followed a lot of islamic things. Since birth i have regarded Allah as god. And every time i pray/make a wish i do it in his name. But nowadays through the internet i have come to understand how others follow islam. So my question is, is our lord so shallow that he will send people to endure hellfire for something like not eating halal meat, or not praying 5 times a day, or not covering up as a women?

I have lived my life without harming anyone and will continue to do so, I’ll always live as a good person. Isn’t that enough?

I mean is it not enough that i do not harm anyone else?

Will our lord really judge if someone is good or bad based on what meat they eat rather than if they have lived a honest life or not?

Suppose there are 2 people:

1. is a bad person who has murdered but follows the lord with Everything he needs to do (5 prayes, halal meat etc)
2. has lived a honest life, had never harmed a soul and is very kind but doesn’t do things like 5 prayers a day, halal meat etc

SO BOTH ARE GOING TO HELL?!!

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please edit this to make it more readable: grammar, punctuation, capitalization, formatting. Making lists and separated paragraphs is good. Check out the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site and [this section](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/asking) on asking questions. Also, as 1 answer pointed out, restricting your question to one exact question would be helpful. Please clarify exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe in Allah and Prophet Muhammad S.A.W and the articles of faith in Islam which means believing in Allah, Angels, The Books which Allah sent, Prophets and Messengers of Allah, The Last Day, Allah's predestination and you do your best by following Quran and Sunnah of Prophet Muhammad S.A.W while believing Islam is completely true and then die as a Muslim without doing Kufr and Shirk then it means you are on a right path. Remember you have to think for yourself. Allah S.W.T is not evil. He has shown a clear path to us and we should follow Quran and Sunnah.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked so many question in what is supposed to be a one question post. I too have only a little known here is what my opinion is,  about your questions and concerns.

1. No, you don’t have to do and follow each and every thing described by Islam. Per the teachings of our beloved Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), for each good deed you will get a reward (say good points), and for each bad deed or sin you will get a bad point. On the day of judgment, there will be scale to measure both the good and bad points. If someone’s good points is more than bad points, then they go to heaven. Those who have more bad points than the good will be at the discretion of Allah, for He will forgive and decrease the bad points and increase the good points and then send them to Heaven. The sole right to decide lies with Allah regarding who to forgive and who not to. But it is expected that those who try their best to follow the orders of Allah, but due to some reason couldn’t follow some, feel guilty in their hearts about it, and request forgiveness to Allah in this world will be the ones.
2. You mentioned examples of two men one good in dealings but not in worship the other good in worship but bad in dealings. My opinion is that it is extremely unreasonable to be judge by ourselves and say one will go to heavens and the other will not. This is because it is at the sole discretion of Almighty Allah to do so and should not be our business. Both are wrong according to the teachings of Islam. And in my opinion, person 1 is more on wrong path. Islam is a whole way of life, and not just the name of some worship.

To conclude, I‘d say that any amount of theoretical and philosophical discussion about Islam is useless unless you believe that Allah is one, He created the world and everything we see (and don’t see). Since He is the King of kings, He has the right to order anything He wish. Our life in this world is just a test. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

To give a good answer to your question would require a long discourse on the dynamics of the Day of Judgment. What I am about to do is, insha‘allah, tell you about 3 major events that Allah and His Messenger (alaihi salaam) told us about regarding the Day of Judgment, and explain a few key concepts that might make certain realities about your Lord clear to you.

The three events I want to tell you about are:

- the Grand Inquisition;
- the Settling of Debts; and
- the Weighing of Deeds.
- -   *

THE GRAND INQUISITION

We each have two angels with us writing down everything we say and do (Qur‘an 50:17-18). They are compiling a Book that is going to contain a perfect account of the lives we lived here in the dunya. We are going to be presented with those Books on the Day of Judgment, which is itself a major event, and Allah is going question us about the contents of our Books.

This questioning will be a terrible event for those who were habitual sinners, because, on the Day of Judgment, everyone will be forced to accept Truth, and all will know that evils and sins spell disaster.

“On the Day when every soul will be confronted with all the good that it has done and all the evil it has done, IT WILL WISH THAT THERE WAS A GREAT DISTANCE BETWEEN IT AND ITS EVIL. Allah Himself is cautioning you, and Allah is full of kindness to those who serve Him.” Qur‘an 3:30

But the situation will  be quite different for the righteous. The righteous have been promised an easy reckoning, (84:7-9). And it‘s not that their Books won‘t contain any sins, because everybody sins, but Allah says that the righteous (meaning those who fulfilled their duties as muslims and didn‘t make a habit of wronging others) will not have to answer for their sins. This is part of what it means to receive mercy from Allah on the Day of Judgment.

“Such are they from whom We shall accept the best of their deeds AND PASS OVER THEIR BAD DEEDS.” Qur‘an 46:16

The point of me sharing this with you is to show you, first and foremost, that Allah favors those who strive to please Him. EVERYONE will receive justice on the Day of Judgment. No one will be wronged. But the only ones to receive mercy will be those who feared the Reckoning so much that they actively sought it (Allah‘s Mercy) out in this world with regular worship, good deeds, just dealings with others, and overall conformance to the command of Allah. People “who are certain about the Hereafter” (2:1-4) will strive hard to do all of these things. It is when we get caught up in the dunya that we neglect the acts that will save us and then wonder if Allah will “be shallow enough” to make us eat the fruit of our negligence.

TRUTH: If we don‘t actively pursue Allah‘s Mercy we will have to face His Justice. So we have a choice to make.

- - *

THE SETTLING OF DEBTS

Let‘s take a closer look at Allah‘s Justice. This will address your question about the person who was good at worshipping but did a lot of harms to others...

One of the names of the Day of Judgment is the Yawm-ut-Taghaabun - the Day of Mutual Loss and Gain. The reason for this is because it will be a day when (1) people who wronged others will lose their good deeds to those they wronged; and/or (2) people who wronged others will gain some of the bad deeds of those they wronged.

@datakeen mentioned the weighing of good deeds against bad deeds. That comes after the settling of debts.

Doing wrong creates a debt that must be paid, and it WILL be paid - in this world or in the next.

If our wrong is against Allah then there are a number of ways we can sqash the debt. We can do a good deed to cancel out the bad one, (11:114). Or we can make tawbah and be forgiven, (39:53).

But if our wrong is against a creature of Allah, then things are a little different. If we can get them to forgive us then their forgiveness will squash the debt. Otherwise we have to try to make it right with them by compensating them for their loss and harm, if they will accept compensation.

If we go to the Hereafter carrying debts to people then that is where we will have to pay the debt off. On the  Day of Judgment there is only one thing we can pay with - our good deeds.

There is a well known hadith where the Prophet (a.s.) asked his Companions, “Who is the poor one among us?” They said, “The one who has no wealth and no property.” The Prophet (a.s.) said, “A poor one of my Ummah is the one who appears on the Day of Judgment having performed salat, paid zakat, observed the fasts of Ramadan, and fulfilled all other obligations. But they also abused someone, slandered someone, misappropriated money from  someone, shed the blood of someone unjustly, or beaten someone unjustly. Each one of them will be given a share of his good deeds. If he does not have enough good deeds to pay off all these debts then their sins will be transferred to his account and he will then be thrown into the Fire.”

That is the Justice of Allah. True righteousness  includes respecting the rights of Allah‘s creatures, not just offering Him ritual worship.

- - *

THE WEIGHING OF THE DEEDS

“We shall set up scales of justice for the Day of Judgment, so that not a soul will be dealt with unjustly in the least. And if there be the weight of a mustard seed We will bring it, and We are enough to take account.” Qur‘an 21:47

“Then he whose balance (of good deeds) will be heavy, will be in a life of  good pleasure and satisfaction. But he whose balance will be light, his mother will be the Pit. And what will explain to you what she is? A Fire blazing fiercely!” Qur‘an 101:6-11

The people who outright reject Faith are lost, and this event is proof of that. In this event Allah is going to weigh people‘s good deeds against their bad deeds. But the kufaar are not going to have any good deeds to counterbalance their bad deeds, because Allah has said that He is not going to give the good deeds of  the kufaar any weight, (3:116-117; 18:103-106; 25:21-23).

This event will be iffy for certain types of muslims. By the Grace of Allah our good deeds will reach the akhirah to help us. But our bad deeds will also be there to work against us, (as they did during the settling of debts). These are the difficulties that will come from being negligent of the Deen in this Dunya, missing prayers, partaking of haraam foods and substances, and allowing our thinking to be far too heavily influenced by our kufaar associates or the sentiments of the society we may be living in. We accumulate A LOT of sins and are not active enough in the doing of good. During the weighing of deeds we are going to regret this.

- - *

Allah the Most High can never be accused of being shallow. It is we who are short-sighted and shallow. We have been fully informed and amply warned about the Day of Judgment and the Hellfire. We have been shown the way to avoid the Fire and all hardships of  the Day of Judgment. But we don‘t like the Guidance BECAUSE IT INTERFERES WITH OUR ENJOYMENT OF THE DUNYA. But this dunya is NOTHING in the True scheme of things.

Our Lord is not a sadist. He does not want to punish anyone, (4:147). He sent us His Guidance to allow us to do all we can to AVOID His Punishment, (2:38-39). He has generously offered to count each good deed we do as 10 good deeds, while counting each bad deed as only one bad deed, (6:160), AND He has offered to forgive ALL bad deeds (except shirk), (39:53; and 4:48, 116).

In return for all of that He has asked us to devote our whole selves to Him. He wants us to believe in Him alone, pray regularly, be kind to others, abstain from the worst sins, be conservative in our spending, dress modestly, be polite and courteous when we interact with others, don‘t be sexually promiscuous, be just and fair to everyone, and stand ready to advance or defend His Deen. None of that makes for a bad life.

It is people who are shallow and foolish. Allah is Akbar!

I hope some good comes from this answer.

Ma‘as‘salaam

Answer (score 0):

**Brother, these are very good questions.**

The fact that you have allah in your heart and that you have a fear of allah will be enough for you to go to haven so long you don't commit other greater sins. Since, we know allah swt is the most merciful. I believe some sins are forgivable. If you hurt someone then its not so easy to get forgiveness since allah swt is also just.
With that said, I'd like you to know.. allah has put rules for us to follow and we can't find our own ways but at the same time.. when you expect forgiveness from allah you are actually showing sings of true believer. We will be saved by our prophet mohammed pbuh and allah will have mercy for his umma, insallah.
Last but not least.. please remember just like every law you break the punishments are different some big some small and by breaking the same law again and again despite being a small law. the punishment can become severe, the law of allah is similar.

*In short don't commit shirk, live good life, don't kill, don't rape, don't steal, don't lie, be good to neighbors and follow allah's teaching as much as you can from the quran and the sahi hadiths and you will be in good shape... that won't get you to jannatul ferdous but I believe allah will have mercy for the little crimes and forgive us to a corner of the lowest level of haven.. somewhere.. in a corner. :)*